# Javascript: How can I count the number of lines of a text element inside a DOM element such as <li>

Tags: javascript, html

My question is, if there is a way in javascript to count the number of lines of an element such as :

```
<li classname="link-link"> Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
since the 1500s, when an unknown </li>
```

With no line length being set. This example could be in 2,3 or 4 lines. There are similar questions to this, but none gave the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get the height and line height then round that to get your answer.

HTML:

```
<li id="link-link"> Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown </li>
```

JS (Jquery):

```
var height = $("#link-link").height()
var fontSize = $("#link-link").css('font-size');
var lineHeight = Math.floor(parseInt(fontSize.replace('px','')) * 1.5);

console.log(Math.ceil(height / lineHeight));
```

Pure JS:

```
var el = document.getElementById('link-link');

var style = window.getComputedStyle(el, null).getPropertyValue('font-size');
var fontSize = parseFloat(style); 

var lineHeight = Math.floor(fontSize * 1.5);
var height = el.clientHeight;

console.log(Math.ceil(height / lineHeight));
```

[JSFiddle w JQuery](https://jsfiddle.net/z455vw5w/) | [JSFiddle with out JQuery](https://jsfiddle.net/z455vw5w/2/)

Comment: Is there a way to do it in pure javascript

Comment: Sure give me one second

Comment: @JAYNATHAN see my answer now for both versions. Also please accept this as the answer if it is what you needed :)

Comment: your answer doesn't work,when I decrease the width of the output tab and the `unknown` word drops to the 4th line

Answer (score 0):

This code works for any Kind of elements:

HTML:

```
<div><span class="Text" id="g1" >
                This code works for any Kind of elements: bla blo bli bla blo bli bla blo bli bla blo bli bla blo bli bla blo bli bla blo bli bla blo bli bla blo bli bla blo bli bla blo bli bla blo bli bla blo bli bla blo bli bla blo bli bla blo bli bla blo bli bla blo bli bla blo bli </span>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.Text{font-size: 28px;}
@media screen and (max-width: 780px) {
            .Text{font-size: 50px;}
        }
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function getStyle(el,styleProp)
{
    var x = el;
    if (x.currentStyle)
        var y = x.currentStyle[styleProp];
    else if (window.getComputedStyle)
        var y = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(x,null).getPropertyValue(styleProp);
    return y;
}
function calculateLineHeight (element) {

  var lineHeight = parseInt(getStyle(element, 'line-height'), 10);
  var clone;
  var singleLineHeight;
  var doubleLineHeight;

  if (isNaN(lineHeight)) {
    clone = element.cloneNode();
    clone.innerHTML = '<br>';
    element.appendChild(clone);
    singleLineHeight = clone.offsetHeight;
    clone.innerHTML = '<br><br>';
    doubleLineHeight = clone.offsetHeight;
    element.removeChild(clone);
    lineHeight = doubleLineHeight - singleLineHeight;
  }

  return lineHeight;
}

function getNumlines(el){return Math.ceil(el.offsetHeight / calculateLineHeight (el))}
console.log(getNumlines(document.getElementById('g1')))
```